# Routes in Laravel does not work in production mode

Tags: laravel

I have made a production in Laravel and deployed the site. The problem is that none of my routes, except for the routes for auth, like log in/log out are working after deployment. My own routes which I created in my web.php are not working. On my local machine its working just fine though. The error I get is:

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
View [my_blade_file] not found.

Have anyone had the same problem?

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that a view (blade file) could not be found. Have you checked if you deployed all of your `resources/views` directory correctly?

Comment: Could you post your file structure?

Comment: All files are in resources/views. On my server I have myapp/resources/views and outside myapp I have put css/js/vendor and index.php in my public_html

Comment: It actually says: /home/myapp/myapp/resources/views/profile/settings.blade.php not found and I think its weird its goes for myapp twice...

Comment: @Mathayas Is there same directory structure in your local machine and live server??

Comment: @Kabelbaan No its not the same, on my local machine I have myapp/public/index.php and on the server I have index.php in my public_html, outside my myapp-dictionary. But I have changed the routes in the index.php file so the first page is loaded but not my routes...

Comment: This seems to be a URL-rewriting issue if you have **myapp** in the path twice. What directory did you upload your Laravel application to on the server, and what does the **.htaccess** file there look like?

Comment: @MartinBean I created a new map in root on the server --> myapp. In the root folder I have domains/myapp/public_html where I have my index.php file. This is the .htaccess: RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$ RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

Answer (score 2):

I removed everything from the server and ran

> php artisan config:clear
>
> php artisan route:clear

in my project before uploading it again, and it worked! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `index.php` file:

`index.php`

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/myapp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: This is how it looks on the server:
/ 
-- myapp 
-- domains/myapp/public_html

So I changed it to $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../myapp/bootstrap/app.php';

And then the site loaded at least, but some of the routes are still not working